# How to create PocketBook-compatible BMP files using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, ebook, bmp

PocketBook 611 is a black-and-white e-book reader. PocketBook 611 (and models of similar age, before touch displays were introduced) uses a very specific BMP format for its so-called "Power-off Logo" (wallpaper for e-ink display, when it is turned off).

I am able to create compatible BMP files using Paint.NET, but I would like to automate my workflow and use ImageMagick instead. The correct BMP format is detected by `file` as:

```
$ file good.bmp 
good.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 600 x 800 x 8, resolution 3779 x 3779 px/m, 256 important colors, cbSize 481078, bits offset 1078
```

But when I am creating BMP files using ImageMagick (e.g. `convert input.jpg output.bmp`), I get an error on the PocketBook about incompatible bitmap image format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the following [`convert`](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command:

```
convert input.jpg -type Grayscale -colorspace Gray -colors 255 -compress None BMP3:output.bmp
```

Replace `convert` with [`magick`](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick.php) if your ImageMagick installation doesn't include `convert`.

In script form for automation:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]
then
    echo "Specify filename"
    exit 1
fi

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    from="$1"
    to="${1%.*}.bmp"
    shift
    echo "'$from' -> '$to'"
    convert "$from" -type Grayscale -colorspace Gray \
        -colors 255 -compress None BMP3:"$to"
done
```

The script can be used in a directory of input files like so: `./pocketbook-convert.sh *.jpg *.png`

If the images are already cropped and rotated, ImageMagick can also resize them to the correct size:

```sh
convert "$from" \
  -gravity center -resize 600x800^ -extent 600x800 \
  -type Grayscale -colorspace Gray -colors 255 -compress None BMP3:"$to"
```

#### Explanation

Prefix `BMP3:` is needed to specify [version of BMP format](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported), because by default regular `BMP` is used, which is BMP version 4. See also list of formats via `identify -list format`:

```
$ identify -list format | grep BMP
      BMP* BMP       rw-   Microsoft Windows bitmap image
     BMP2* BMP       rw-   Microsoft Windows bitmap image (V2)
     BMP3* BMP       rw-   Microsoft Windows bitmap image (V3)
     WBMP* WBMP      rw-   Wireless Bitmap (level 0) image
```

I figured out the exact parameters for other options by comparing output of `identify -verbose` between a good file and a bad file. Also, [this answer about DirectClass and PseudoClass](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382758/53143) helped understand what's going on with color maps and color spaces. Relevant parts of output of `identify -verbose`:

```
$ identify -verbose good.bmp | less
  Format: BMP3 (Microsoft Windows bitmap image (V3))
  Class: PseudoClass
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Grayscale
  Colors: 250
  Compression: None
  Filesize: 481078B
```

`Filesize` is relevant, because with "correct" options, all files have almost exact same size around 470 kilobytes.

Documentation of grayscale BMP conversion options: [`-type Grayscale`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#type), [`-colorspace Gray`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace), [`-colors 255`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colors), and [`-compress None`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress).

Documentation of resizing options: [`-gravity`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) (has to go before `-extent`!), [`-resize`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize), [`-extent`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent).